# How to pass PHP session variables to JavaScript while script is running

Tags: php, ajax, session-variables

I am using AJAX to pass a value as a parameter to a function in a class which takes a little while to execute. I want to display output messages in the browser as the PHP script runs.

I have tried setting a session variable in a few places in the script, and am using AJAX to try to read the session variable every second.

Here is some code

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
    var outputs = setInterval(displayOutputMessage, 1000);

    $.post('ajax.php', {action:'run', id:12345}).then(() => {
        clearInterval(outputs);
    });

    function displayOutputMessage() {
        $.post('ajax.php', {action:'getOutputMessages'}).then(data => {
            if (data !== 'session not set') {
                $('#output').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
switch ($_POST['action']) {
    case 'run':
        $x = new LongScript();
        $x->longFunction($_POST['id']);
        break;


    case 'getOutputMessages':
        echo isset($_SESSION['outputMessage']) ? $_SESSION['outputMessage'] : 'session not set';
        break;
}
```

```
session_start();

class LongScript
{
    public function longFunction($id) {
        $items = XYZ::getItems($id);
        foreach ($items as $k => $item) {

            //code omitted
            $_SESSION['outputMessage'] = "output message ($k)";

            $suppliers = XYZ::getSuppliers($item['oem'])

            foreach ($suppliers as $supplier) {
                //code omitted
                $_SESSION['outputMessage'] = "another message ($k)";
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that the output only displays the session variable data after the long function has completed its execution. The script can take from 45 seconds to 3 minutes to run and the code within the loops do take some time to run so I am expecting to see some other output messages other than the last one. I have also tried using `flush()` after setting the session variable and this didn't make a difference.

I am open to using a different way to do the same thing if using a session for this isn't possible. The page itself will only be accessible to fewer than 5 users.

Comment: Look towards header() function to send back header with your variable before the rest.

Comment: I think you will have to actually close the session, with something like [session_commit()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-commit), and then reopen it before you update the session variable again, to actually write the session variable to the session file.